# SpringMVC: The precedence of @RequestMapping and Static Resource serving

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, web-development-server

I have the following mapping for a controller handler method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "login.html")
public String doLogin(Model model) {
    return "login";
}
```

And I have the following configuration for static `*.html` resource:

```
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
     registry.addResourceHandler("*.html").addResourceLocations(("/static/"));
}
```

So suppose I am visiting `login.html`, which one will take the precedence?
Any official document about the `by-design` behavior?

### ADD 1 Some background

I want to use pure `HTML+JS` for the view of my application. Since I don't know how to return an HTML from a controller method (someone said it is not possible), I decided to serve the static HTML with `static resource handler`. But it seems I still have to configure a handler method mapped to the root path `/` for my web application. Although I have already placed an `index.html` under the `/static/` path. i.e., I must have this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String welcome(Model model) {
    return "redirect:index.html"; //must prefix with "redirect:"
}
```

Otherwise, when I hit `http://mysite/`, I will get a `404` error.

### ADD 2 -- some experiment result

It seems the precedence is like this:

> request comes -> Controller request mapping -> If no valid mapping in controller, check static resource handler -> if no valid static resource found, 404, Oops...

### ADD 3 - 3 possible options to serve static resource.

I moved the question to here:

[Static resource serving in SpringMVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34105401/static-resource-serving-in-springmvc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The WebMvcConfigurationSupport Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.html) describes the `HandlerMapping` beans registered by default (i.e. by `@EnableWebMvc`) and their order of precedence.

When mapping URL paths, the order is:

1. Annotated controller methods
2. Directly to view names
3. Controller bean names
4. Serve static resource requests
5. Forward requests to the default servlet

Even if you're building a "pure HTML+JS" application, you might want to turn that `index.html` into a template anyway and leverage some Spring MVC features, such as resource handling and cache busting for your static resources. Take a look at [this Devoxx talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7cemYpV1fNI).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am new to Spring and I prefer not to jump to Spring Boot too soon. Could you elaborate a bit more about `turning index.html into a template`?

Comment: The Spring team recommends Spring Boot for both experienced developers and newcomers http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#overview-getting-started-with-spring . As for your other questions, I think they're orthogonal to your first question and belong to a separate SO thread. Remember, this should be also useful to others and not overwhelm readers with content and multiple questions.

Comment: Got it. I will start another thread for my `ADD 3` after I prepare my words.

Comment: @BrianClozel Is it possible to do/fix the following: `@GetMapping("/x/**") public String fw() { return "forward:/x/index.html"; }` <-- this of course creates an endless loop - is it possible to prevent this? Motivation: Javascript-Frontend with router in history mode must forward all URLs /x/** to javascript router. If the code above can be fixed, all javascript assets can be placed e.g. in `/src/main/resources/static/x/`. Of course different names can be used e.g. `x` and `y` ;-), but this is not as nice and runs into problems when running a js dev server. Thanks in advance!